# Cannot pivot table with my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table which looks like this -

```
Id  AttributeName   AttributeValue
A1  Atr1            A1V1
A1  Atr2            A1V2
A1  Atr3            A1V3
A2  Atr1            A2V1
A2  Atr2            A2V2
A2  Atr3            A3V3
```

Each ID in this table has the exact same attributes, ie ATR1, ATR2, ATR3. The values of these attributes is unique.

I want to pivot this table and get the following output -

```
Id  Atr1 Atr2 Atr3
A1  A1V1 A1V2 A1V3
A2  A2V1 A2V2 A2V3
```

How do I do this ?

I tried a query and it failed with the error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

```
-- Create a temporary table
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(Id varchar(25),
 AttributeName varchar(30),
 AttributeValue varchar(30))
-- Load Sample Data
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr1', 'A1V1')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr2', 'A1V2')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr3', 'A1V3')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr1', 'A2V1')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr2', 'A2V2')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr3', 'A3V3')
SELECT Id, [Atr1], [Atr2],[Atr3]
FROM
( 
SELECT ID, AttributeName, AttributeValue
FROM @MyTable) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT 
(
    AttributeValue
    FOR AttributeName IN ([ATR1], [ATR2], [ATR3])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: This example was adapted from - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PIVOTData&referringTitle=UNPIVOTData

Comment: Is there a possibility that you will have more than one repeated attribute name called `A1`, etc for each `id`?

Comment: @bluefeet - Unlikely. But suppose that happens, then how would I make the query for that ? Thanks.

Comment: here comes the pivot master @bluefeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to expand on the other answers, the PIVOT function requires some type of aggregation.  Since the value that you want to convert from a row into a column is a string, then you are limited to using either the `max()` or `min()` aggregate function.

While [@Muhammed Ali's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253383/426671) answer will work when you have a single `AttributeName`/`AttributeValue` pair, if you have multiple pairs for each `ID`, then you will only return either the `max` or `min` value.

For example if your sample data is:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr1', 'A1V1');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr1', 'A1V4');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr2', 'A1V2');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr3', 'A1V3');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr1', 'A2V1');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr2', 'A2V2');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr3', 'A3V3');
```

Even though you have multiple rows for the combination of `A1` and `Atr1`, the other queries  are only returning the `max(attributevalue)`:

```
| ID | ATR1 | ATR2 | ATR3 |
|----|------|------|------|
| A1 | A1V4 | A1V2 | A1V3 |
| A2 | A2V1 | A2V2 | A3V3 |
```

I would guess that you would actually want to return all of the combinations. I suggest expanding your query to include the windowing function, `row_number()` in your query.  This query generates a unique value that will then be included in the grouping aspect of the PIVOT and will allow you to return more than one row for each ID.

By adding the `row_number()`, the query will be similar to the following:

```
SELECT Id, [Atr1], [Atr2],[Atr3]
FROM
( 
  SELECT ID, AttributeName, AttributeValue,
    row_number() over(partition by id, attributename
                      order by attributevalue) seq
  FROM @MyTable
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT 
(
    max(AttributeValue)
    FOR AttributeName IN ([ATR1], [ATR2], [ATR3])
) AS pvt
order by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25742). You will get a result that returns all rows:

```
| ID | ATR1 |   ATR2 |   ATR3 |
|----|------|--------|--------|
| A1 | A1V1 |   A1V2 |   A1V3 |
| A1 | A1V4 | (null) | (null) |
| A2 | A2V1 |   A2V2 |   A3V3 |
```

If you are having trouble grasping the concept of PIVOT, then I would suggest look at using a combination of an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result. You can then see the grouping of the sequence/id:

```
SELECT Id, 
  max(case when attributename = 'Atr1' then attributevalue end) Atr1,
  max(case when attributename = 'Atr2' then attributevalue end) Atr2,
  max(case when attributename = 'Atr3' then attributevalue end) Atr3
FROM
( 
  SELECT ID, AttributeName, AttributeValue,
    row_number() over(partition by id, attributename
                      order by attributevalue) seq
  FROM @MyTable
) AS SourceTable 
group by id, seq
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25745)

Comment: Yes, blue feet, your assumption is correct. I want all pairs to be returned. By the way, how does MAX know which AttributeValue is maximum in the AttributeValue column and how to assign it to the right ID ?

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT I'm not sure I understand you question, the row_number is ordering the data by the `attributevalue` and then the pivot is using a combination of the max aggregate but the key is it is grouping the data by the `id` and the sequence number created by the row_number - that grouping gets the data in the correct rows/columns.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT I added another version of the query using an aggregate function with a CASE expression, this let's you see how the data is being grouped by the `id` and the `seq` values.

Comment: @bluefeet - Thank you very much indeed. To honour you, I will buy a pair of blue socks today. :P Btw, you have cold feet ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(Id varchar(25),
 AttributeName varchar(30),
 AttributeValue varchar(30))
-- Load Sample Data
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr1', 'A1V1')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr2', 'A1V2')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A1', 'Atr3', 'A1V3')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr1', 'A2V1')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr2', 'A2V2')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('A2', 'Atr3', 'A3V3')
SELECT Id, [Atr1], [Atr2],[Atr3]
FROM
( 
SELECT ID, AttributeName, AttributeValue
FROM @MyTable) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(AttributeValue)
    FOR AttributeName IN ([ATR1], [ATR2], [ATR3])
) AS pvt
```

You are missing the function in you Pivot table syntax

**Result Set**

```
Id  Atr1    Atr2    Atr3
A1  A1V1    A1V2    A1V3
A2  A2V1    A2V2    A3V3
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammed. I did not know that I have to also use a function around one of my columns. Btw, how does the MAX function help in this case ? How does it pick the right value from the AttributeValue column ?

Comment: this is PIVOT syntax you have to have some sort of Function there to make pivot work, since it is a varchar column MAX function works just fine. read here for more details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks again. Would there be any problems if it was a non-varchar column ?

Comment: and if this answer helped please accept the answer, for Non-character datatype INT columns you can use any aggregate function its only the the varchar datatype you have limited options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, 
       max(case AttributeName when 'Atr1' then AttributeName else '' end) as atr1,
       max(case AttributeName when 'Atr2' then AttributeName else '' end) as atr2,
       max(case AttributeName when 'Atr3' then AttributeName else '' end) as atr3,
       AttributeValue
  from YourTable
group by id, AttributeValue
order by id
```