# How to convert row values to columns with dynamic columns count?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have the following data:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [ColumnA] INT
    ,[ColumnB] INT
    ,[ColumnC] INT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC])
VALUES   (5060,1006,100118)
        ,(5060,1006,100119)
        ,(5060,1006,100120)
        ,(5060,1007,100121)
        ,(5060,1007,100122)
        ,(5060,1012,100123)

SELECT [ColumnA]
      ,[ColumnB]
      ,[ColumnC]
FROM @DataSource
```

[image]

and I need to converted like this:

[image]

The difficult part is that the data is dynamic (I do not know how many columns I will have) and I am not able to use a standard pivot here because the values in `ColumnC` are different and as a result I am going to have as many columns as values appears in `ColumnC`.

Is there any technique to achieve this?
Any kind of help (answers, articles, suggestions) will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot pivot table with my query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253345/cannot-pivot-table-with-my-query)  or even this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119162/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: @bluefeet No, these answers can't solve my issue.

Comment: Yeah actually they can, did you look to see if they could be modified for your situation?

Comment: No, you are right, using `ROW_NUMBER` I can transform my data and do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion whenever you are working with PIVOT is to alway write the query first with the values hard-coded, then you can easily convert the query to a dynamic solution.

Since you are going to have multiple values of `columnC` that will be converted to columns, then you need to look at using the `row_number()` windowing function to generate a unique sequence for each `columnc` based on the values of `columnA` and `columnB`.

The starting point for your query will be:

```
select [ColumnA],
  [ColumnB],
  [ColumnC],
  'SampleTitle'+
  cast(row_number() over(partition by columna, columnb
                          order by columnc) as varchar(10)) seq
from DataSource;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717/5).  This query will generate the list of new columns names `SampleTitle1`, etc:

```
| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC |          SEQ |
|---------|---------|---------|--------------|
|    5060 |    1006 |  100118 | SampleTitle1 |
|    5060 |    1006 |  100119 | SampleTitle2 |
|    5060 |    1006 |  100120 | SampleTitle3 |
```

You can then apply the pivot on `columnC` with the new column names listed in `seq`:

```
select columnA, columnB, 
  SampleTitle1, SampleTitle2, SampleTitle3
from
(
   select [ColumnA],
    [ColumnB],
    [ColumnC],
    'SampleTitle'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by columna, columnb
                              order by columnc) as varchar(10)) seq
   from DataSource
) d
pivot
(
  max(columnc)
  for seq in (SampleTitle1, SampleTitle2, SampleTitle3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717/4).

Once you have the correct logic, you can convert the data to dynamic SQL.  The key here is generating the list of new column names.  I typically use `FOR XML PATH` for this similar to:

```
select STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(seq) 
                from
                (
                  select 'SampleTitle'+
                    cast(row_number() over(partition by columna, columnb
                                            order by columnc) as varchar(10)) seq
                  from DataSource
                ) d
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717/7). Once you have the list of column names, then you will generate your sql string to execute, the full code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(seq) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'SampleTitle'+
                        cast(row_number() over(partition by columna, columnb
                                                order by columnc) as varchar(10)) seq
                      from DataSource
                    ) d
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT columnA, ColumnB,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
               select [ColumnA],
                [ColumnB],
                [ColumnC],
                ''SampleTitle''+
                  cast(row_number() over(partition by columna, columnb
                                          order by columnc) as varchar(10)) seq
               from DataSource
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(columnc)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717/3). These give a result:

```
| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | SAMPLETITLE1 | SAMPLETITLE2 | SAMPLETITLE3 |
|---------|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|    5060 |    1006 |       100118 |       100119 |       100120 |
|    5060 |    1007 |       100121 |       100122 |       (null) |
|    5060 |    1012 |       100123 |       (null) |       (null) |
```